# How to use FinancialData[] function to filter stocks based on closing price?

Tags: functions, filtering, curated-data

I was wondering if it were possible to use the [`FinancialData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FinancialData.html) function to return a list of stocks based on a price filter, ie. return all NYSE stocks, that had a closing price between \$10-\$12?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
stocks=FinancialData["NYSE:UN*", "Lookup"];
prices=FinancialData[#,"Close"]&/@stocks;
data=Map[<|"symbol"->#1,"price"->#2|>&@@#&,Thread[List[stocks,prices]]];
```

```
data//Dataset
```

[image]

```
f=Function[{data,lower,upper},
Cases[data,KeyValuePattern["price"->x_/;lower<=QuantityMagnitude@x<=upper]]//Dataset];
f[data,5,10]
```

[image]

#### By the way

[image: Mathematica graphics]

 Is it possible without an API limitation?

Comment: +1 Note, that `FinancialData[ "name" ]` does not necessarily give the closing price.

Comment: Thanks! I've fixed the post just now :)

Answer (score 3):

A variation to Xminer's answer:

```
With[
    {
        names = FinancialData["NYSE:UN*", "Lookup"], (* use "NYSE:*" for more *)
        lower = 10,
        upper = 100 (* use 12 for your example *)
    }
    ,
    FinancialData[ #, {"Name", "Close"} ]& /@ names // RightComposition[
        Map[ AssociationThread[ {"Name", "Price"} -> ## ] & ],
        Query[ Select[ lower <= QuantityMagnitude[#Price] <= upper & ], "Name" ]
    ]
]
```

> {Unilever, Unum, Univar Inc}